# Having issues matching local and foreign fields in a $lookup pipeline for a MongoDB aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions, mongodb-lookup

I have a two different collections, one for *emailtemplates*, and one for *emails*. And what I'm trying to do is write an aggregate pipeline that will show how many times each template has been sent using the templates *name* from the *emailtemplates* collection. I know I could just execute a pipeline on the *emails* collection and count each one by the template name, but that will exclude templates that have never been sent.

Here are some example documents I worked up...

```json
// Example emailtemplate documents:
[
  {
    "name": "WELCOME-01",
    "channel": "email",
    "status":"active",
    "title": "Hello, welcome {firstname} {lastnane}",
    "parameters":[{
      "name": "firstname",
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },{
      "name": "lastname",
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }],
    "body":"Dear {firstname}, Welcome to the club"
  },
  {
    "name": "GOODBYE-01",
    "channel": "email",
    "status":"active",
    "title": "Hello, welcome {firstname} {lastnane}",
    "parameters":[{
      "name": "firstname",
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },{
      "name": "lastname",
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }],
    "body":"Dear {firstname}, were sorry to see you go"
  },
  {
    "name": "YOURE-FIRED-01",
    "channel": "email",
    "status":"active",
    "title": "Hello, welcome {firstname} {lastnane}",
    "parameters":[{
      "name": "firstname",
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },{
      "name": "lastname",
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }],
    "body":"Dear {firstname}, Pack your stuff and go"
  }
]


// Example email documents:
[
  {
    "templateName": "WELCOME-01",
    "recipient": "john.doe@gmail.com",
    "parameters": {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe"
    }
  },
  {
    "templateName": "WELCOME-01",
    "recipient": "david.chappelle@gmail.com",
    "parameters": {
      "firstName": "David",
      "lastName": "Chappelle"
    },
  },
  {
    "templateName": "GOODBYE-01",
    "recipient": "the.joker@gmail.com",
    "parameters": {
      "firstName": "The",
      "lastName": "Joker"
    }
  }
]
```

So you can see how each *email* document has the *templateName* value which matches with the *name* from each *emailtemplates* document. And what I'm trying to do is select from the *templateName* collection and show how many *emails* documents are associated to it.

I know how to do it using the *localField* and *foreignFIeld* options:

```js
db.notificationtemplates.aggregate([
  {
      $lookup:{
        from: "notifications",
        localField: "name",
        foreignField: "templateName",
        as: "notifications"
      }
   },
   {
    $project:{
      _id: 0,
      templateName: "$name",
      amountSent: { $size: "$notifications"}
    }
   }
 ]);
```

Which gives me the results:

```js
[
  { templateName: 'WELCOME-01', amountSent: 2 },
  { templateName: 'GOODBYE-01', amountSent: 1 },
  { templateName: 'YOURE-FIRED-01', amountSent: 0 }
}
```

And that works just fine, but I need to add some logic to the *$lookup*, which means I need a *$pipeline* in there, which means I can't simply use the *localField* and *foreignField*. Otherwise I get the error:

> MongoServerError: $lookup with 'pipeline' may not specify 'localField' or 'foreignField'

Here's the query I've written thus far to try to do the same thing:

```js
 db.emailtemplates.aggregate([
  { $match:{channel: 'email'} },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "emails",
      let: {
        templateName: "$templateName",
        name: "$name"
      },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: {$eq: [ "$$templateName","$name"] } } },
        { $project:{
            "templateName":"$templateName",
            "name":"$name"
        } }
      ],
      as: "emails"
    }
  }
])
```

Here are the results of the query above:

```js
[
  {
    "name": "WELCOME-01",
    "channel": "email",
    "status":"active",
    "title": "Hello, welcome {firstname} {lastnane}",
    "parameters":[{
      "name": "firstname",
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },{
      "name": "lastname",
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }],
    "body":"Dear {firstname}, Welcome to the club",
    "emails":[
      {
        "templateName": "WELCOME-01"
      },
      {
        "templateName": "WELCOME-01",
      },
      {
        "templateName": "GOODBYE-01"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "GOODBYE-01",
    "channel": "email",
    "status":"active",
    "title": "Hello, welcome {firstname} {lastnane}",
    "parameters":[{
      "name": "firstname",
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },{
      "name": "lastname",
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }],
    "body":"Dear {firstname}, were sorry to see you go",
    "emails":[
      {
        "templateName": "WELCOME-01"
      },
      {
        "templateName": "WELCOME-01",
      },
      {
        "templateName": "GOODBYE-01"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "YOURE-FIRED-01",
    "channel": "email",
    "status":"active",
    "title": "Hello, welcome {firstname} {lastnane}",
    "parameters":[{
      "name": "firstname",
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },{
      "name": "lastname",
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }],
    "body":"Dear {firstname}, Pack your stuff and go",
    "emails":[
      {
        "templateName": "WELCOME-01"
      },
      {
        "templateName": "WELCOME-01",
      },
      {
        "templateName": "GOODBYE-01"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Note**: I'm only outputting the *templateName* now so I can see what documents get matched for the *emails* value.

If you look at the *emails* value for each document that's output, it doesn't at all only look for the emails with the *templateName* matching the local *name* value of the *emailtemplate* documents.

The output I'm expecting to see would be something more along the line of:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "WELCOME-01",
    "channel": "email",
    "status":"active",
    "title": "Hello, welcome {firstname} {lastnane}",
    "parameters":[{
      "name": "firstname",
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },{
      "name": "lastname",
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }],
    "body":"Dear {firstname}, Welcome to the club",
    "emails":[
      {
        "templateName": "WELCOME-01"
      },
      {
        "templateName": "WELCOME-01"
      }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "GOODBYE-01",
    "channel": "email",
    "status":"active",
    "title": "Hello, welcome {firstname} {lastnane}",
    "parameters":[{
      "name": "firstname",
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },{
      "name": "lastname",
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }],
    "body":"Dear {firstname}, were sorry to see you go",
    "emails":[
      {
        "templateName": "GOODBYE-01"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "YOURE-FIRED-01",
    "channel": "email",
    "status":"active",
    "title": "Hello, welcome {firstname} {lastnane}",
    "parameters":[{
      "name": "firstname",
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },{
      "name": "lastname",
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }],
    "body":"Dear {firstname}, Pack your stuff and go",
    "emails":[]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close actually. You just mixed up the variables and the field names. Note that `$$` indicates variable in MongoDB aggregation pipeline. In your `$let` clause, you are using the value from `emailtemplates.name` to create variable `name`. So for the `$lookup` sub-pipeline you should compare `$$name` with `$templateName`, which refers to `emails.templateName` as you are looking up the `emails` collection.

The correct syntax should be like this:

```js
db.emailtemplates.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      channel: "email"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "emails",
      let: {
        templateName: "$templateName",
        name: "$name"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$templateName",
                "$$name"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            "templateName": "$templateName",
            "name": "$name"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "emails"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3Qgio76Oi58)

Comment: I got it working shortly after posting this (as always..), and it was very similar to yours. But in the `let` part, I had to set the `name` to `$$CURRENT.name`, then I could equate `$templateName` to `$$name`. Ended up working fine.